# Need to add number's of marker at same location

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I'm currently developing application which using Google Maps.

I'm trying to display the multiple markers around the same location. I've got the map working but can't seem to marker.Just highlight only one marker.If suppose i am inserting 4 markers with same location name. I need to display four marker at same time.
But in my case i am not displaying four markers at a same time.
Here is my component and ui

Component.ts

```
    getmapdata() {


        this.Service.Map().subscribe
            (response => {
                this.element = response;
                this.markers = [];
                this.mapLoading = false;
                if (response.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++) {
                        this.marker = new IMarker();

                        this.element[i].lat = Math.random() * 0.1 + this.element[i].lat;
                        this.element[i].long = Math.random() * 0.1 + this.element[i].long;

                        this.marker.positions = [this.element[i].lat, this.element[i].long];
                        this.centerPosition.lat = this.element[i].lat;
                        this.centerPosition.lng = this.element[i].long;


                        this.markers.push(this.marker);
                    }
                }
                else this.markers = undefined;
            },
            (err => {
                //console.log(err);

                this.toastr.error(JSON.parse(err._body).Message);
            }));

    }


showInfoWindow(t) {
        var e = t.target;
        let lat: any, lng: any;
        lat = parseFloat(e.getPosition().lat().toString()).toFixed(4);
        lng = parseFloat(e.getPosition().lng().toString()).toFixed(4);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++) {
            let elat: any = parseFloat(this.element[i].lat.toString()).toFixed(4),
                elng: any = parseFloat(this.element[i].long.toString()).toFixed(4);

            if (lat === elat && lng === elng) {
                this.info = this.element[i].cityname + " - " + this.element[i].sitename;
            }
        }
        e.nguiMapComponent.openInfoWindow("iw", e)
    }
```

.html File

```
  <div *ngIf="markers != undefined && markers.length != 0" class="sebm-google-map-container">
                                <ngui-map zoom="4" [center]="{lat: centerPosition.lat, lng: centerPosition.lng }" scrollwheel="true" zoomControl=true
                                          mapTypeControl=false streetViewControl=false fullscreenControl=true>
                                    <marker *ngFor="let pos of markers"
                                            on-mouseover="showInfoWindow($event)"
                                            [position]="pos.positions"
                                            [icon]="{
                                                    url: 'Contents/Icons/blue_marker.png',
                                                    anchor: [16,16],
                                                    size: [32,32],
                                                    scaledSize: [32,32]
                                                }"
                                            (click)="gotoSite(pos)">

                                    </marker>

                                    <info-window id="iw">
                                        <div>{{ info }}</div>
                                    </info-window>

                                </ngui-map>




                            </div>
```

And .css file

```
 styles: [
        `
    .sebm-google-map-container, .sebm-google-map-container ngui-map {
       height: calc(50vh - 117px);
     } 

    [hidden] { display: none !important;}

    #divNoMapData {
        position:absolute !important; 
        width:100%;
        display: table;
    }
    h1 {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
  `
    ],
```

Comment: if all the marker are in the sampe location  you can see only the top most.. so you should slightly change the coord of each marke for see  all icons

Comment: ofcousre but according to my requirement i don't want to change even 0.01 positions.Is there any other solution??

Comment: (I use normally  0,0001 so the different position in evidend with high zoom)  ) but if you don't want change the location then  You can see  for marker cluster .

Comment: ok.. Can you provide me link about marker cluster/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering